# How to QRegExp "[propertyID="anything"] "?

Tags: regex, qt, qt5, qt5.4, qregexp

I am parsing a file which contains following packets:

```
[propertyID="123000"] { 
  fillColor : #f3f1ed;
  minSize : 5;
  lineWidth : 3;
}
```

To scan just this `[propertyID="123000"]` fragment I havre this QRegExp

```
QRegExp("^\b\[propertyID=\"c+\"\]\b");
```

but that does not work? Here I have example code to parse that file above:

```
QRegExp propertyIDExp= QRegExp("\\[propertyID=\".*\"]");
propertyIDExp.setMinimal(true);

QFile inputFile(fileName);
if (inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    QTextStream in(&inputFile);
    while (!in.atEnd())
    {
        QString line = in.readLine();

        // if does not catch if line is for instance
        // [propertyID="123000"] {
        if( line.contains(propertyIDExp) )
        {
            //.. further processing
        }
    }
    inputFile.close();
}
```

Comment: `QRegExp("\[propertyID=\"\d+\"\]")`   ?????????? what is `c`

Comment: @vks c = character ?

Comment: No its not.....use `\d` for `numbers` and `.` for any character

Comment: I think you misunderstood the docs: *c - A character represents itself unless it has a special regexp meaning. e.g. c matches the character c.*

Comment: CSS does not have a regular syntax and cannot be parsed using a regex! The *reg* in *reg*ex means regular expressions - a way to specify regular syntax parsers. When the language doesn't have a regular syntax, you can't use a regex to parse it (duh). At best you're creating a parser that will work only for some very specific examples of CSS, and will reject most valid CSS making your users hate you with a passion. Such hacks are highly unprofessional.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following expression:

```
QRegExp("\\[propertyID=\"\\d+\"]");
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vC9jO0/1)

In Qt regex, you need to escape regex special characters with double backslashes, and to match digits, you can use the shorthand class `\d`. Also, `\b` word boundary prevented your regex from matching since it cannot match between the string start and `[` and between `]` and a space (or use `\B` instead).

To match anything in between quotes, use a negated character class:

```
QRegExp("\\[propertyID=\"[^\"]*\"]");
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/vC9jO0/2)

As an alternative, you can use lazy dot matching with the help of `.*` and [`QRegExp::setMinimal()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#setMinimal):

```
QRegExp rx("\\[propertyID=\".*\"]");
rx.setMinimal(true);
```

In Qt, `.` matches *any* character including a newline, so please be careful with this option.

Comment: d is for decimal. What can I user for any string.. The Id may also contain strings like [propertyID="circle"]

Comment: I updated the answer with `QRegExp("\\[propertyID=\"[^\"]*\"]");` suggestion. If you want to exclude results with empty string inside the double quotes, use `+` instead of `*`.

Comment: If you need to only allow English characters inside the quotes, use `QRegExp("\\[propertyID=\"[A-Za-z]*\"]");`.

Comment: QRegExp("\\[propertyID=\".*\"]") is not working for me. I have english chars, numerals and some special chars like '?' QRegExp("\\[propertyID=\"[^\"]*\"]"); neither.

Comment: Could you please post all the relevant code (the lines that use the regexp), and add more real-life examples? I am surprised that `.*` with `setMinimal(true)` does not work for you. [See this demo](https://regex101.com/r/vC9jO0/3) showing it really matches anything inside the quotes.

Comment: Perhaps either one of those will work for you: 1) `QRegExp propertyIDExp("\\[propertyID=\".*\"\\]");`, 2) `QRegExp propertyIDExp("[[]propertyID\\s*=\\s*\".*\"[]]");`, 3) `if (propertyIDExp.indexIn(line) > -1) {...};`

Answer (score 0):

```
QRegExp("\\[propertyID=\".+?\"\\]")
```

You can use `.`.It will match any character except `newline`.Also use `+?` to make it non greedy or it will stop at the last instance of `"` in the same line